# tkinter topmost and overridedirect

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to write a program with a window set to always at the top and without the border. So I write the following program, which doesn't work as intended (macOS Sierra, 10.12.3):

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root,text='some text').pack()
root.attributes('-topmost',True)
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.mainloop() #this one doesn't work
```

screenshot of the failed one

[image]

However, when I change the sequence of overridedirect and attributes, surprisingly it worked.

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root,text='some text').pack()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.attributes('-topmost',True)
root.mainloop() #this one works
```

screenshot of the successful one

[image]

Can someone please tell me why the sequence of those two lines matters?

Comment: Probably the only explanation is that tkinter is a little buggy on OSX.

Comment: Both scripts gave the same result (your latter image) on ubuntu/linux.